# Fast way to find diamonds

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can someone tell me a very easy way to find diamonds because it takes me 10 min to just find like 10 diamonds mining on y11. I have also tried y6 and I didn’t find diamonds. I only found diamonds because I got lucky going in one of the caves I found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy) or [Mining for Diamonds in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389284/mining-for-diamonds-in-minecraft)

Comment: 10 diamonds within 10 minutes is a lot, provided you are not using looting and efficiency pickaxes. Many players have experienced the pain of finding no diamonds in an entire hour.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the fastest way is to create an efficiency IV pickaxe or more with fortune III, and then get into a 1x1 hole with a water bucket at y-11 or y-12. You can insta-mine stone, allowing you to mine as fast as you can move.